# Angularjs NVD3 Custom X Axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqN8dNodPSlhLVhl27ge?p=preview) where I want to wrap the X Axis labels to next line.  I have the following configuration in my controller to customize the x axis but it is not working

```
xAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'X Axis',
    tickFormat: function(d){
        var words = d.split(' '),label = '';

        for (var i=0; i< words.length; i++) {
            label += words[i] + "\n"; // does not work either
            // label += "<tspan class='x'>" + words[i] + "<tspan>"; // does not work either
        }

        return label;
     }
 }
```

How should i make the code such that x axis does not overlap the labels. I am looking for [same result as this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) but I could not understand how can I apply the logic without touching the NVD3 Directive I am using. Is it possible ?